# How to implement slice in Python 3?

Tags: python, slice

I read something about slice in Python 3. Then I wrote a program, tried to implement `__getitem__(self, slice(s))`. Code goes below:

```
class NewList:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        print('new list')
        self._list = lst
    def __getitem__(self, x):
        if type(x) is slice:
            return [ self._list[n] for n in range(x.start, x.stop, x.step) ]  #error?
        else:
            return self._list[x]
    ...

nl1 = NewList([1,2,3,4,5])
nl1[1:3]  #error occurs
```

Then I found out `x.step` is `None`, which made range raise an exception.
So, how should I implement the `__getitem__` method?

Comment: Also, your `NewList` class should inherit from `list`...

Comment: @JBernardo --Do u mean that I should avoid using slice objects explicitly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `slice.indices` method. Given the length of your sequence, it returns a tuple of start, stop, step:

```
>>> s = slice(2, 5, None)
>>> s.indices(10)
(2, 5, 1)

>>> [x for x in range(*s.indices(10))]
[2, 3, 4]

>>> s.indices(3)
(2, 3, 1)

>>> s.indices(0)
(0, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Where can we find documentation om the slice class?

Comment: [slice.indices](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=slice%20indices#slice.indices) docs

Answer (score 4):

In the case where you don't know the length of your object there is an obvious trick to circumvent this mandatory parameter. For example an infinite sequence's **getitem** can look like this:

```
  def __getitem__( self, key ) :
    if isinstance( key, slice ) :
       m = max(key.start, key.stop)
       return [self[ii] for ii in xrange(*key.indices(m+1))]
    elif isinstance( key, int ) :
       #Handle int indices
```

It will only fail if you don't give start and stop but with checking for None this could be handled too.

Comment: `xrange` doesnt exist in python3, instead we should use `range`. also using this implementation you can't have slices like `[:4]` because `max` can't handle `None` type. Instead you should check if start and stop are not `None`, and if they are, assign them to zero and len of items, respectively. Also, it's good to include `key.step` in `range`, too.

Answer (score 1):

If `x` is a slice, you can do the same as the other condition:

```
return self._list[x]
```

Comment: absolutely yes, but I just want to know how to do it myself

Comment: @Alcott, not sure what you mean by "do it myself".

Comment: sorry, I mean I want to know how the __getitem__(self,slice) implemented in list.

Answer (score 0):

how about `x.step or 1`?

```
class NewList:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        print('new list')
        self._list = lst
    def __getitem__(self, x):
        if type(x) is slice:
            return [ self._list[n] for n in range(x.start, x.stop, x.step or 1) ]  #error?
        else:
            return self._list[x]

nl1 = NewList([1,2,3,4,5])
nl1[1:3]
```

Comment: ya, it's way circumventing the problem, but according to what I read, no.